# jUnit in Eclipse is throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, junit

I've taken a look at the other jUnit null point exceptions, and none of them appear to address what I'm experiencing. I'm running Eclipse 4.3.1 with Ubuntu 12.04.

I've set up a jUnit class with the Eclipse wizard and thought I followed all of the tutorial.  The code is;

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openhab.action.videoanalytics.AwarenessTypes.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ThreeMinuteRun {

String cameraId = "cam1test";
String videoStream = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mjpg/video.mjpg"; //ip obfuscated for this online question
String format = "MJPG";
MotionDetectionType motionType= MotionDetectionType.basic;
AwarenessAnalytics AA = new AwarenessAnalytics();
String maskFilename = "/home/will/odev/MotionDetect/src/main/resources/DrivewayMaskWhite.png";
MotionDetectionState motionDetectionState = MotionDetectionState.on;
String directoryStore = "/media/PENDRIVE/alertImageTest/";

@Test
public void testSetVideoSource() {
    try {
        AA.setVideoSource(cameraId, videoStream, format, motionType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("IOException in setVideoSource");
    }
}

@Test
public void testAddListener() {
    AA.addListener(new DetectionListener());
}

@Test
public void testSetFramesToExaminePerSecond() {
    AA.setFramesToExaminePerSecond(cameraId, 1);
}

@Test
public void testSetMotionDetectionType() {
    AA.setMotionDetectionType(cameraId, motionType);
}

@Test
public void testSetImageStoreLocation() {
    AA.setImageStoreLocation(directoryStore);;
}

@Test
public void testSetsecsUntilMotionCeasedOption() {
    AA.setsecsUntilMotionCeasedOption(7);
}

@Test
public void testSetSizeSensitivity() {
    AA.setSizeSensitivity(cameraId, 4);
}

@Test
public void testSetDebugState() {
    AA.setDebugState(true, 10);
}

@Test
public void testSetMotionDetectionState() {
    AA.setMotionDetectionState(cameraId, motionDetectionState);
}

@Test
public void testSetLightFalseAlarmAdjustment() {
    AA.setLightFalseAlarmAdjustment(cameraId, 5);
}

@Test
public void testSetMaskImage() {
    AA.setMaskImage(cameraId, maskFilename);
}

@Test
public void testSetMaskState() {
    AA.setMaskState(cameraId, true);
}

@Test
public void testGetAlertImages() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testGetAlertVideo() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testStart() {
    AA.start();
    //then sleep for 3 minutes
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(360000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Q. Should this be passed up or just ignored if it happens occasionally?
        //throw new IOException ("Sleep problem ", e);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

/**@Test
public void testRun() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}*/



@Test
public void testStop() {
    AA. stop();
}

}
```

The error msg I get is rather terse;

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching ThreeMinuteRun (1)".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This three minute run has turned into a "3 Hour Tour"...

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

I changed the setVideoSource preamble to @Before (though it is not mandatory to run before most of the other calls) and I changed the Start preamble to @After, which *does* require the video source to be set first.

```
@Before
public void testSetVideoSource() {
    try {
        AA.setVideoSource(cameraId, videoStream, format, motionType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("IOException in setVideoSource");
    }
}

@After
public void testStart() {
    AA.start();
    //then sleep for 3 minutes
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(360000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //throw new IOException ("Sleep problem ", e);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I still get the same exception.

Just a note: I have a non-jUnit test driver that is currently working superbly, I'm trying to improve my skills (and add discipline) by

Analytics Awareness is a basic Thread (for now) that spawns a VideoAnalytics thread for each camera (only one under test at this time). The component set is currently working with my non-jUnit driver, providing the results I need for now.

**EDIT 2:**

I just re-ran my existing non-jUnit test driver and it is still functioning normally, with the AwarenessAnalytic class behaving normally (with a few non-exception logic bugs to work through, naturally).

**EDIT 3:**

Changed the testSetVideoSource method to init, with no change in the outcome (still throws null pointer exception).

```
@Before
public void init() {
    try {
        AA.setVideoSource(cameraId, videoStream, format, motionType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("IOException in setVideoSource");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 4:**

I created a more basic test from a copy of the first test above, removing all of tests procedures except for the following;

```
@Before
public void init() {
    try {
        AA.setVideoSource(cameraId, videoStream, format, motionType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("IOException in setVideoSource");
    }
}

@Test
public void testAddListener() {
    AA.addListener(new DetectionListener());
}

@After
public void testStart() {
    AA.start();
    //then sleep for 3 minutes
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(360000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //throw new IOException ("Sleep problem ", e);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The error message I now get is virtually the same, though there is no "(1)" after the JUnit test class name;

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching ThreeMinuteRunSimple".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I just tried running this in Debug, also as a JUnit test, thought the same exception occurs right away, before anything else happens.

Thoughts?

Comment: A little more lines from the stacktrace will be helpful

Comment: This is all that came up in the error msg, even after clicking on "Details". Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute `AA.start()` before to execute each target method like `AA.addListener(new DetectionListener());`, you should use `@Before` annotation.
Then you can execute `AA.start()` method before execute each `@Test` target method. If you execute the method after the test, you should use `@After` annotation.

```
public class ThreeMinuteRun {

    ...

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        AA.start();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        AA.stop();
    }

    ...

    @Test
    public void testAddListener() {
        AA.addListener(new DetectionListener());
    }
}
```

When `testAddListener` test called, it will be call in the order as follows:

1. `AA.start();`
2. `AA.addListener(new DetectionListener());`
3. `AA.stop()`

Comment: Ok, I tried that (see EDIT update), though I'm still getting the exact same (terse) exception.

Comment: which @Test case/method did you run in particular?

Comment: In Eclipse, I right-clicked on the ThreeMinuteTest class in Explorer,  then -> Run As -> jUnit test. Is this correct, or am I supposed to take other steps?

Comment: I've tried a simpler test, with the same results, even when running in Debug (which won't even start). Thoughts?

Comment: I mean, instead of trying to run the complete class at a time as single test case. First run each @test case individually, for example, you can select "testSetVideoSource" and then righ click and select 'Run As' and see how it works

Comment: Ok, I tried running just the setVideoSource() (which is now titled "init()"). I still get the same exception.

Comment: Which line throwing the exception? Isn't it problem of `AwarenessAnalytics` class?

Comment: then try run the test in debug mode and see where exactly it fails

Comment: It doesn't even get to the source lines of code in the debugger, it fails immediately.

Comment: And @KouheiMikami , AwarenessAnalytics runs superbly with a plain (non-JUnit) Java test driver, so I can't see that being the problem.

I can't help but wonder if there is something majorly wrong with how I've set it up. I followed the recommended examples, and all of the JUnit test class definition went very smoothly.

Comment: It is still not working, but you and others provided appropriate answers, so I'm accepting the closest one to being right (from a JUnit perspective). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

A common bug is you expect that the tests are run after each other. Each test is fully independed, so don't expect states from other runs.

Try putting your constructor logic in a init method which you invoke on start of each test. That helped me. If this does not work directly try this also with your other constant values.

```
public class ThreeMinuteRun {

    String cameraId = "cam1test";
    String videoStream = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mjpg/video.mjpg"; //ip obfuscated for this online question
    String format = "MJPG";
    MotionDetectionType motionType= MotionDetectionType.basic;
    AwarenessAnalytics AA; // <---------------  CHANGED -------------
    String maskFilename = "/home/will/odev/MotionDetect/src/main/resources/DrivewayMaskWhite.png";
    MotionDetectionState motionDetectionState = MotionDetectionState.on;
    String directoryStore = "/media/PENDRIVE/alertImageTest/";

    private void init() {
        AA = new AwarenessAnalytics();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetVideoSource() {
        init();
        try {
            AA.setVideoSource(cameraId, videoStream, format, motionType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail("IOException in setVideoSource");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the only test I have so far. Or did you mean the @Test calls within the test?

Comment: Every method with the @Test annotation will been run in a seperat instance.

Comment: Oh, then that may be the reason, let me restructure and retry. Thanks, rekire!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, even with Before and After mods. Pls see updated description.

Comment: That `@Before` and `@After` never worked for me too. Try putting your constructor logic in a init method which you invoke on start of each test. That helped me.

Comment: When you say "init method", do you really mean init()? Is this recognized by jUnit and run first? Or did you mean something else?

Should I run a separate test first to setVideoSource, or will the AwarenessAnalytic instance go away after the first test?

Comment: I changed the testSetVideoSource(<params>) to init(<params>) and kept the Before tag. It still throws the null pointer exception.

Comment: Did I do what you meant by your suggestion, or is there something else I should be doing? Thanks

Comment: try to copy the full stacktrace

Comment: The exception information I showed above is all I get from Eclipse currently, which comes in a pop up window (nothing shows on the console). I clicked on the "Details" button, which gave the information shown above. Is there a different place I should be looking? I'm running on Ubuntu Studio 12.04 and Eclipse 4.3.1, btw

Comment: I don't know I start this in a gradle environment. I have no idea where you can find more details in eclipse

Comment: I restructured to the init() method you noted above (I didn't see it until just now!), and I still get the same exception right away.

I also moved the class instantiation right into the testSetVideoSource method, still with the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to execute something before each test, i'm not sure you need this though.

```
@Before 
public void method()
```

This method is executed once before any tests are started.

```
@BeforeClass 
public static void method()
```

this also looks a bit buggy

```
@Test
public void testSetImageStoreLocation() {
    AA.setImageStoreLocation(directoryStore);; <==
}
```

*EDIT:* Maybe you should switch to the JUnit dependency instead of the one you are using. I'm not sure all other libraries have the same annotations could be the reason you are getting null pointer exception if you are mixing different test frameworks. Be sure to check that you have the JUnit library in your build path and not just as an import statement.

Comment: Thanks, though am still getting same exception.

Comment: I deleted the extra semi-colon, though still get the same exception. Thanks for pointing that out.

When you are saying "switch to the JUnit dependency", do you mean I should remove my current test driver to a different location? I'm currently commenting out the .start() call (with no complaints from Eclipse), though could that still be a source of the problem?

Comment: I've tried a simpler test, with the same results, even when running in Debug (which won't even start). Thoughts?

Comment: Be sure to check that you have the JUnit library in your build path and not just as an import statement.

Comment: It is there under Libraries, with a JUnit 4 heading. Interestingly, under that are;

- junit.jar (in my Yoxos directory as a plug-ing
- org.hamcrest.org<long version number>.jar, also under my Yoxos directory as a plug-in. I believe this is a dJUnit plug-in, which also shows up when I go to run the regular JUnit test.

Is this somehow interfering? I've also tried to run the dJUnit option, but it gives the same results.

Comment: Maybe some of your methods arent functioning then. Have you checked the constructors when you build the objects?

Comment: I've removed all but the simplest operations and the constructor for AwarenessAnalytics is working as it should.